# Android - Quais técnologias de dados, SQL?, noSQL?, local database + servidor database?

Tags: android, estrutura-de-dados, cliente-servidor, banco-de-dados

Quais as boas praticas usada para o fornecimento, armazenamento, fluxo, de dados, em uma aplicação `Android`?

Por exemplo, o app **EasyTaxi**, **iFood**, entre outros:

- Qual a necessidade/vantagem de um banco de dados local(quais informações são ideais para utilizar um database, como por exemplo, `SQLite`)?;
- Qual o cenário da aplicação em que o uso de um banco de dados compartilhado em um servidor para o grande controle de fluxo de informações(Isso seria uma implementação de no `SQL`)?;
- Esses apps, eles tem 2 tipos de login, um do app e outro pelo facebook, como é gerenciado os dados de autenticação para manter a fidelidade de que o usuario que esta logando no app é o mesmo que loga usando a api do facebook?;
- O EasyTaxi possui um modulo para o Taxista e outro para o passageiro, qual técnologia de Dados é utilizado para fazer o fornecimento, armazenamento, fluxo, entre um modulo e o outro?;

Realmente saber o melhor caminho para que isso aconteça e quais técnologias usar em um cenário que o app abrange um grande fluxo de informações e ao mesmo tempo manter a fidelidade das trocas de mensagens do app, entre os módulos, o usuário, o servidor, é importante, eu sei como fazer isso com `Delphi`, mas mobile é totalmente novo e tudo é muito lindo.

Eu já havia lido e usado um pouquinho `mongoDb`, `nodeJS`, banco de dados relacionais, facebook api, mas quero saber o caminho reto, afinal somos de exatas e essa refêrencia é muito importante.

Comment: Talvez seja mais interessante separar em várias perguntas. Cada um desses tópicos é uma resposta inteira por si só.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Vou falar com base nos apps que eu desenvolvi.

> Qual a necessidade/vantagem de um banco de dados local(quais
>   informações são ideais para utilizar um database, como por exemplo,
>   SQLite)?;

*Eu utilizei banco local para dados que não são alterados, como por exemplo dados do usuário do app como Altura, Idade, Nome, Sexo.*

> Qual o cenário da aplicação em que o uso de um banco de dados
>   compartilhado em um servidor para o grande controle de fluxo de
>   informações(Isso seria uma implementação de no SQL)?;

Quando você precisa compartilhar dados entre todos os usuários do app, ou quando eles precisam consumir dados na web, como por exemplo acessar o saldo de algum serviço.

> Esses apps, eles tem 2 tipos de login, um do app e outro pelo
>   facebook, como é gerenciado os dados de autenticação para manter a
>   fidelidade de que o usuario que esta logando no app é o mesmo que loga
>   usando a api do facebook?;

Quando utilizei, ele podia usar OU cadastro do app, OU usar login do Facebook, eu não sei lhe dizer se é fácil mesclar as duas depois de criadas.

> O EasyTaxi possui um modulo para o Taxista e outro para o passageiro,
>   qual técnologia de Dados é utilizado para fazer o fornecimento,
>   armazenamento, fluxo, entre um modulo e o outro?

Tem 2 modos

1 é com base no usuário logado você mostrar uma VIEW diferente na Home, e da Home vai ter o link para todas as views.

2 Criar um APP para cada módulo do módulo usuário (Google PLay) e para módulo ADM (Ad-Hoc)

Eu trabalhei em 5 aplicativos android nativos, isso é o que tenho de experiência, talvez alguém saiba lhe informar melhor.

Comment: Bom, você respondeu certinho todas as perguntas, mas, pela minha inexperiência, eu não soube fazer a pergunta correta. Vou marcar sua resposta como certa e elaborar algo mais coeso com o que eu busco.